# MS SQL Table of CRON Future Runs

Tags: sql-server, cron, cronexpression

I have a need to create a table/view containing a full and complete list of future CRON executions for a period of time, e.g. from 12 months ago to 12 months in the future.

My source data is in MS SQL 2012 and contains the following sample information;

```
TASK   SCHEDULE                 SCHEDULESTART              SCHEDULEEND
T1     0 0 0 ? * MON            2015-04-08 16:15:09.557    2015-04-20 00:00:00.000
T2     0 0 0 ? * MON            2015-05-22 15:56:48.140    2015-07-27 00:00:00.000
T3     0 0/56 * * * ?           2015-06-25 10:17:07.387    2015-06-25 15:00:00.000
T4     0 10/15 21 3,19 5-9 ?    2015-06-25 10:18:48.077    2015-08-28 10:17:15.000
```

Unfortunately as MS SQL doesn't support/contain a JVM, I'm limited (I think) to programmatically breaking this out into it's components parts.

I've managed to break out he parts of the expression with the following;

```
    ;WITH cte (SCHEDULE,SCHEDULESTART,SCHEDULEEND,SCHED_Attributes)
    AS
    (
    SELECT SCHEDULE,SCHEDULESTART,SCHEDULEEND,
        CONVERT(XML,'<Product><Attribute>' 
            + REPLACE([SCHEDULE],' ', '</Attribute><Attribute>') 
            + '</Attribute></Product>') AS SCHED_Attributes
    FROM USCH_TASK
    )
    SELECT 
        SCHEDULE,SCHEDULESTART,SCHEDULEEND,
        SCHED_Attributes.value('/Product[1]/Attribute[1]','varchar(25)') AS sched_seconds,
        SCHED_Attributes.value('/Product[1]/Attribute[2]','varchar(25)') AS sched_minutes,
        SCHED_Attributes.value('/Product[1]/Attribute[3]','varchar(25)') AS sched_hours,
        SCHED_Attributes.value('/Product[1]/Attribute[4]','varchar(25)') AS sched_day_of_month,
        SCHED_Attributes.value('/Product[1]/Attribute[5]','varchar(25)') AS sched_month,
        SCHED_Attributes.value('/Product[1]/Attribute[6]','varchar(25)') AS sched_day_of_week,
        SCHED_Attributes.value('/Product[1]/Attribute[7]','varchar(25)') AS sched_year 
    from cte
```

This results in (for example)

```
sched_seconds   sched_minutes   sched_hours sched_day_of_month  sched_month sched_day_of_week   sched_year
0               0               0           ?                   *           MON                 NULL
0               0               0           ?                   *           MON                 NULL
0               0/56            *           *                   *           ?                   NULL
0               10/15           21          3,19                5-9         ?                   NULL
```

Main thrust of this question is then how to handle the component parts of this, * and ? are easy enough, ranges (e.g. 5-9 or MON-THU) are pretty OK, but am struggling with how to determine where have specific dates/months (e.g. 3,19) or more complex configurations (such as the last example above or days of month ="1-3,6-7,15")

```
CASE 
         WHEN CHARINDEX('*',Prod_Attributes.value('/Product[1]/Attribute[6]','varchar(25)')) > 0 THEN 'Y'
         WHEN CHARINDEX('?',Prod_Attributes.value('/Product[1]/Attribute[6]','varchar(25)')) > 0 THEN 'Y'
         WHEN CHARINDEX('MON',Prod_Attributes.value('/Product[1]/Attribute[6]','varchar(25)')) > 0 THEN 'Y'
         WHEN CHARINDEX('SUN-TUE',Prod_Attributes.value('/Product[1]/Attribute[6]','varchar(25)')) > 0 THEN 'Y'
         WHEN CHARINDEX('SUN-WED',Prod_Attributes.value('/Product[1]/Attribute[6]','varchar(25)')) > 0 THEN 'Y'
         WHEN CHARINDEX('SUN-THU',Prod_Attributes.value('/Product[1]/Attribute[6]','varchar(25)')) > 0 THEN 'Y'
         WHEN CHARINDEX('SUN-FRI',Prod_Attributes.value('/Product[1]/Attribute[6]','varchar(25)')) > 0 THEN 'Y'
         WHEN CHARINDEX('SUN-SAT',Prod_Attributes.value('/Product[1]/Attribute[6]','varchar(25)')) > 0 THEN 'Y'
         ELSE 'N'
    END as DOWMon
```

However this approach wouldn't work for day 1 of the month as the code

```
WHEN CHARINDEX('1',Prod_Attributes.value('/Product[1]/Attribute[4]','varchar(25)')) > 0 THEN 'Y'
```

would also find value 10 through 19, 21 and 31!

Any tips or tricks are gratefully received!

Andy

Comment: Just me, but i don't think SQL is the best choice for this task. Maybe have a look into "CLR SQL Server User-Defined Functions" and maybe something like Quartz.NET or ncrontab libraries

Comment: I'm inclined to agree, unfortunately this is something we might need to roll out to multiple projects and may have some issues getting this through the different DBA's